# Validating an IP with regex

Tags: regex

I need to validate an IP range that is in format 000000000 to 255255255 without any delimiters between the 3 groups of numbers. 
Each of the three groups that the final IP consists of should be 000 (yes, 0 padded) to 255.

As this is my 1st stackoverflow entry, please be lenient if I did not follow etiquette correctly.

Comment: Your IP addresses consists of only 3 numbers and not 4?

Comment: Could you please give us some examples of the type of strings you have in input? Examples would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^([01]\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3}$
```

Which breaks down in the following parts:

1. 000-199
2. 200-249
3. 250-255

If you decide you want 4 octets instead of 3, just change the last `{3}` to `{4}`.  Also, you should be aware of IPv6 too.

Comment: Btw, the inner parentheses are not necessary because concatenation has a higher precedence than alternation.

Answer (score 5):

I would personally not use regex for this. I think it's easier to ensure that the string consists of 9 digits, split up the string into 3 groups of 3-digit numbers, and then check that each number is between 0 and 255, inclusive.

If you really insist on regex, then you could use something like this:

```
"([0-1][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]){3}"
```

The expression comprises an alternation of three terms: the first matches `000-199`, the second `200-249`, the third `250-255`. The `{3}` requires the match exactly three times.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common question. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) is a nice intro page on regexps, that has this case as an example. It includes the periods, but you can edit those out easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

for match exclusively a valid IP adress use

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}
```

instead of

```
([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}
```

because many regex engine match the first possibility in the OR sequence

you can try your regex engine with : 10.48.0.200

Answer (score 0):

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

I use this RegEx for search all ip in code from my project