# What is the regular expression to find string of the format http://69.39.233.135:8032?

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validating an IP with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555847/validating-an-ip-with-regex)

I need the regular expression for finding strings like followings in Java:

```
http://69.39.233.135:8032
http://83.133.127.104
http://119.207.75.238:11120
```

Comment: You want to find all IP-only urls? The ports? The IPs?

Comment: Edited to correct JAVA to Java - it's not an acronym.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Regular expressions are well explained here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Have you tried reading the tutorials at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)?  This is an excellent learning opportunity, as this is a simple question yet figuring it out will save you tons of time on similar problems in the future.  A tool like [Regex Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) will also be a big help.

Comment: As an amateur network admin, I'm not sure if it is secure to post live IPs and port numbers on the wild.

Comment: Thank you @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft. Great resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern would fetch the desired results:

```
http://\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?::\d{1,5})?
```

Matches an IP after http:// with an optional port.

Note that this is a simplified validation of an IPv4 and will only match that they are one the correct format and not a valid one. And remember to add an extra backslash to escape each backslash in java.

Here's an example in java:

```
String text = "http://69.39.233.135:8032 http://83.133.127.104 http://119.207.75.238:11120";        
String pattern = "(http://\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3}(?::\\d{1,5})?)";

Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(text);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
http://69.39.233.135:8032
http://83.133.127.104
http://119.207.75.238:11120
```

Comment: That does not validate anything though. I'd prefer to use (\d{1,3}) four times to capture each octet in case validation is needed. Validating in regexp is not worth it IMO (see Regexident's answer to find out why :-)

Comment: Just like @VinkoVrsalovic already said this would match `http://999.999.999.999:999`, which is an invalid IP in many respects.

Comment: OP never mentioned anything about validation; only to find substrings in that format and thus this would do great.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer without taking into account language, cause it shows the way to think when crafting regexes

- String starts with protcol
- You want to match protocol : `http://`
- You have 4 groups of digits separated by dots
- you have an optional port, which is semicolon then numbers
- Srings is ended after that

If you don't take into account that numbers must be smaller than 255, that some combinations are forbidden, you end up with

```
 ^http:\/\/(\d+\.){3}(\d+)(:\d+)?$
```

Comment: This would match `http://999.999.999.999:999`, which is an invalid IP in many respects.

Comment: Question is not about validating ip (it might be implicit in the question but not stated). Anyway, if this would match, checking values afterwards is easy.

Answer (score 0):

These are IPv4 addresses; the newer IPv6 will spread too. Furthermore you might write http://234144234:8080 instead. The second line is for leaving the port number optional.

```
"http\\://\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\:\\d+"
"http\\://\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}(\\:\\d+)?"
```